# Premature exit from Perl File::Find

Tags: regex, perl, recursion, find, directory-traversal

In Perl we usually do a recursive directory traversal using `File::Find` and we often use code similar to below to find certain files based on a pattern.

```
find(\&filter, $somepath);
sub filter {
    my $srcfile = $_;
    if -f $srcfile && $srcfile =~ /<CERTAIN PATTERN>/ {
        <Some processing which requires a premature exit>
    }
}
```

This is generally quite flexible, but there are certain times when we want to prematurely exit the find. Is there a defined way in Perl to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if this possibility could work for you:

`die` inside `find` function and surround the call in an `eval` function to trap the exception and continue execution your program.

```
eval { find(\&filter, $somepath) };
print "After premature exit of find...\n";
```

And inside `filter` function:

```
sub filter {
    my $srcfile = $_;
    if -f $srcfile && $srcfile =~ /<CERTAIN PATTERN>/ {
        die "Premature exit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was the exact thing I was looking for :-). Btw is there any particular reason why you said `Try if this possibility could work for you:`. Is there some scenario when this would fail?

Comment: @Abhijit: Insecurity, nothing else. I'm learning perl but I'm still a newbie and althought I tested it before posting the solution, don't feel sure to say that it is the best solution ever. There are many perl experts in this site who will be able to explain in detail pros and cons of this and other solutions. I just try to help as much as I can, and learn, of course.

Comment: @Birei => If you write it as `eval {...; 1} or print "error string: $@"` then you wont get the error message if `find` ends normally.  This is because `eval` will return the last expression in the block on success, and `undef` on failure.  So ending the block with `;1` turns `eval` into a boolean operator for easy chaining or testing with conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $somepath = q(.);
my $earlyexit;

find(\&filter, $somepath);
sub filter {
    my $srcfile = $_;

    $File::Find::prune = 1 if $earlyexit; #...skip descending directories

    return if $earlyexit;                 #...we have what we wanted

    if (  -f $srcfile && $srcfile =~ /<CERTAIN PATTERN>/ ) {
    #...<Some Processing which requires premature exit>
    #   ...
        $earlyexit = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice hack but Birei's solution is more elegant. Also this is actually not prematurely exiting for the current directory but just skips the remaining processing.